# Freidlin-Wentzell theory: clarification of a theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, estimation, large-deviation-theory

I am studying Freidlin and Wentzell large deviation theory from their 2012 book "Random perturbations of dynamical systems" and I have a problem in justifying two steps of the proof of theorem 1.3. The theorem states

**Theorem**

We assume that there exists a continuous function $\bar{b}(t, x), t > 0,x \in \mathbb{R}^{r}$  such that for any $δ > 0, T > 0, x ∈ R^r$ we have
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn: hp1}
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \mathbb{P} \Big( \Big| \int_{t_0}^{t_0+T}b(\epsilon,t,x,\omega)dt - \int_{t_0}^{t_0+T} \bar{b}(t,x)dt \Big| > \delta \Big) = 0
\end{equation}
uniformly in $t_0 \ge 0$. Then the equation
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn: hp2}
\dot{\bar{x}}_t=\bar{b}(t,\bar{x}_t), \qquad \bar{x}_0=x
\end{equation}
has a unique solution and
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \mathbb{P} \big( \max_{0 \le t \le T}|X_{t}^{\epsilon}-\bar{x}_t| > \delta \big) =0
\end{equation}
for every $T>0$ and $\delta>0$.

---

**Proof**
Since the function $\bar{b}(t,x)$ is continuous, by the mean value theorem we have
$
\int_{t}^{t+\Delta}\bar{b}(s,x) ds =\bar{b}(t,x)\Delta+o(\Delta), \qquad \Delta \to 0
$
Taking into account the first hypothesis, we get
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
|\bar{b}(t,x)-\bar{b}(t,y)| &= \frac{1}{\Delta} \Big| \int_{t}^{t+\Delta} \bar{b}(s,x)ds - \int_{t}^{t+\Delta} \bar{b}(s,y)ds \Big| + \frac{o(\Delta)}{\Delta}\\
& \le  \frac{1}{\Delta} \Big| \int_{t}^{t+\Delta} b(\epsilon,s,x,\omega)ds - \int_{t}^{t+\Delta} b(\epsilon,s,y,\omega)ds \Big| \\
& + \frac{o(\Delta)}{\Delta} +\delta_{\epsilon} \\
& \le K|x-y|+\frac{o(\Delta)}{\Delta} +\delta_{\epsilon}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $\delta_{\epsilon}=\delta_{\epsilon}(t,\omega) \to 0$ in probability as $\epsilon \to 0$. And from this follows the Lipschitz condition on $\bar{b}$ and so the existence and uniqueness.

Here I don't understand how to get $\delta_{\epsilon}$, which I don't even know how it is defined.

I tried in this way: from the hypotesis I remark that $-\delta \le  \int_{t_0}^{t_0+T}b(\epsilon,t,x,\omega)dt - \int_{t_0}^{t_0+T} \bar{b}(t,x)dt \le \delta$
and so, after adding and subtracting both $\int_{t}^{t+\Delta}b(\epsilon,t,x,\omega)dt$ and $\int_{t}^{t+\Delta}b(\epsilon,t,y,\omega)dt$ and use the remark above and I obtain
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
|\bar{b}(t,x)-\bar{b}(t,y)| &= \frac{1}{\Delta} \Big| \int_{t}^{t+\Delta} \bar{b}(s,x)ds - \int_{t}^{t+\Delta} \bar{b}(s,y)ds \Big| + \frac{o(\Delta)}{\Delta}\\
& \le  \frac{1}{\Delta} \Big| \int_{t}^{t+\Delta} b(\epsilon,s,x,\omega)ds - \int_{t}^{t+\Delta} b(\epsilon,s,y,\omega)ds \Big| \\
& + \frac{o(\Delta)}{\Delta} +\frac{2}{\Delta}\delta \\
& \le K|x-y|+\frac{o(\Delta)}{\Delta} +\delta_{\epsilon}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $\delta_{\epsilon}=\frac{2}{\Delta}\delta$. But it doesn't seem right since it is not random and so how can I say that it converges in probability as the quantity of the authors?

The other doubt is some steps after this. I have the estimate that follows:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& \int_{0}^{t} [b(\epsilon,s,\bar{x}_s,\omega)-\bar{b}(s,\bar{x}_s)]ds \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{kt/n}^{(k+1)t/n} [b(\epsilon,s,\bar{x}_s,\omega)-\bar{b}(s,\bar{x}_s)]ds \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{kt/n}^{(k+1)t/n} [b(\epsilon,s,\bar{x}_{kt/n},\omega)-\bar{b}(s,\bar{x}_{kt/n})]ds \\
&+ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{kt/n}^{(k+1)t/n} [b(\epsilon,s,\bar{x}_s,\omega)-b(\epsilon,s,\bar{x}_{kt/n},\omega)]ds \\
&+ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{kt/n}^{(k+1)t/n} [\bar{b}(s,\bar{x}_{kt/n},)-\bar{b}(s,\bar{x}_s)]ds \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{kt/n}^{(k+1)t/n} [b(\epsilon,s,\bar{x}_{kt/n},\omega)-\bar{b}(s,\bar{x}_{kt/n})]ds + \rho_{n,t}^{\epsilon}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where they say that $|\rho_{n,t}^{\epsilon}| \le C/n$ with $C=C(T,K)$. I tried in this way but I'm stuck and don't know how to go on
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
|\rho_{n,t}^{\epsilon}| &\le \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{kt/n}^{(k+1)t/n} |b(\epsilon,s,\bar{x}_s,\omega)-b(\epsilon,s,\bar{x}_{kt/n},\omega)|ds \\
&+ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{kt/n}^{(k+1)t/n} |\bar{b}(s,\bar{x}_{kt/n},)-\bar{b}(s,\bar{x}_s|ds \\
& \le 2K \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{kt/n}^{(k+1)t/n}|\bar{x}_s - \bar{x}_{kt/n}|ds
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Now I don't know how to procede: how can I get the same result as in the book?

**Questions**

1. is what I did at the beginning correct? If not, how do I change it?
2. how do I go on in the second part?
   Thanks to anyone who will have the patience to read and answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, I think you are almost there. When you wrote something like $$-\delta \le  \int_{t_0}^{t_0+T}b(\epsilon,t,x,\omega)dt - \int_{t_0}^{t_0+T} \bar{b}(t,x)dt \le \delta,$$ you should be aware of the randomness contained in $\omega$, so this statement can only hold with certain probability (here with high probability), so the bound on $|\bar{b}(t,x) - \bar{b}(t,y)|$ you wrote only hold with high probability. For the second question I am not completely sure as well. I guess the authors used something like $|\bar{x}_s - \bar{x}_{kt/n}| \leq C/n$ for $s \in [kt/n,(k+1)t/n]$, this can probably be justified by the Lipschitz continuity enjoyed by $\bar{b}$ (maybe we also need to use that $\bar{b}$ is uniformly bounded on a compact time-space region). Hope this helps!